# Exception in Application start method java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException [NO FXML]

Tags: java, exception, javafx

I have small javafx app and i have two errors. As you can see I dont use fxml.
I already tried to clean and build project and then run it again, but still doesnt work. All the solutions I found are related to fxml, but I did not use it. However, I can not find where I'm wrong. Can somebody help me?

Here is my code:

```
Label name = new Label("Name: ");
TextField txName = new TextField();
Label lastname = new Label("LastName  ");
TextField txLastName = new TextField();
Label age = new Label("Age: ");
TextField txAge = new TextField();
Label phoneNumber = new Label("Phone number: ");
TextField txPhoneNumber = new TextField();
Label numberCarLicence = new Label("Car licence number: ");
TextField txNumberCarLicence = new TextField();

  Label choseCar = new Label("Chose car: ");
  TextField txChoseCar = new TextField();
  Label pickLocation = new Label("Pick location: ");
  TextField txPickLocation = new TextField();
  Label backLocation = new Label("Back location: ");
  TextField txBackLocation = new TextField();
  Label pickDays = new Label("Pick days: ");
  TextField txPickDays = new TextField();

GridPane center = new GridPane();
Button btnRent = new Button("Rent");
TableView tableView = new TableView();

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

    UnaryOperator<TextFormatter.Change> phoneNumberJustNumbers = change -> {
        String text = change.getText();
        if (text.matches("[0-9]*")) {
            return change;
        }
        return null;
    };
    TextFormatter<String> textFormatter = new TextFormatter<>(phoneNumberJustNumbers);
    txPhoneNumber.setTextFormatter(textFormatter);

    UnaryOperator<TextFormatter.Change> numberCarLicenceJustNumbers = change -> {
        String text = change.getText();
        if (text.matches("[0-9]*")) {
            return change;
        }
        return null;
    };
    TextFormatter<String> textFormatter1 = new TextFormatter<>(numberCarLicenceJustNumbers);
    txNumberCarLicence.setTextFormatter(textFormatter1);

    UnaryOperator<TextFormatter.Change> pickDaysJustNumbers = change -> {
        String text = change.getText();
        if (text.matches("[0-9]*")) {
            return change;
        }
        return null;
    };
    TextFormatter<String> textFormatter2 = new TextFormatter<>(pickDaysJustNumbers);
    txPickDays.setTextFormatter(textFormatter2);

    UnaryOperator<TextFormatter.Change> ageJustNumbers = change -> {
        String text = change.getText();
        if (text.matches("[0-9]*")) {
            return change;
        }
        return null;
    };
    TextFormatter<String> textFormatter3 = new TextFormatter<>(ageJustNumbers);
    txAge.setTextFormatter(textFormatter3);

    Scene scene = new Scene(center, 1000, 400);

    txChoseCar.setEditable(false);
    txChoseCar.setStyle("-fx-background-color : lightgray");
    txPickLocation.setEditable(false);
    txPickLocation.setStyle("-fx-background-color : lightgray");
    txBackLocation.setEditable(false);
    txBackLocation.setStyle("-fx-background-color : lightgray");
    txPickDays.setEditable(false);
    txPickDays.setStyle("-fx-background-color : lightgray");

    primaryStage.setTitle("Rent a car");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();

    center.add(name, 0, 0);
    center.add(txName, 1, 0);
    center.add(lastname, 0, 1);
    center.add(txLastName, 1, 1);
    center.add(age, 0, 2);
    center.add(txPhoneNumber, 1, 2);
    center.add(phoneNumber, 0, 3);
    center.add(txPhoneNumber, 1, 3);
    center.add(numberCarLicence, 0, 4);
    center.add(txNumberCarLicence, 1, 4);
    center.add(choseCar, 3, 0);
    center.add(txChoseCar, 4, 0);
    center.add(pickLocation, 3, 1);
    center.add(txPickLocation, 4, 1);
    center.add(backLocation, 3, 2);
    center.add(txBackLocation, 4, 2);
    center.add(pickDays, 3, 3);
    center.add(txPickDays, 4, 3);
    center.add(btnRent, 5, 6);

    center.setPadding(new Insets(10, 5, 10, 5));
    center.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    center.setVgap(10);
    center.setHgap(10);

    alert.show();

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

}
```

Stack Trace:

```
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$154(LauncherImpl.java:182)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Children: duplicate children added: parent = Grid hgap=0.0, vgap=0.0, alignment=TOP_LEFT
    at javafx.scene.Parent$2.onProposedChange(Parent.java:454)
    at com.sun.javafx.collections.VetoableListDecorator.add(VetoableListDecorator.java:206)
    at javafx.scene.layout.GridPane.add(GridPane.java:965)
    at cs102projekat.CS102Projekat.start(CS102Projekat.java:125)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$161(LauncherImpl.java:863)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$174(PlatformImpl.java:326)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$172(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$173(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$147(WinApplication.java:177)
    ... 1 more
```

Comment: .fxml is not in the classpath.

Comment: So how I can add fxml

Comment: Are you using any ide like Eclipse or Intellij Idea ?

Comment: NetBeans IDE 8.2

Comment: You can check this link. https://netbeans.org/kb/72/java/javafx-setup.html

Comment: I already started the program and it worked. I did not do anything about 2 hours and now the program will not work

Comment: Did you leave the program running the whole time or did you restart it. Note that a stacktrace for the issue helps us narrow down the issue without having to compile the code, possibly saving us time. be sure to indicate lines in your code occuring in the stacktrace...

Comment: NetBeans worked all the time.

Comment: I updated question with StackTrace

Comment: @Sambit - OP is not using FXML so `.fxml` being in the classpath is irrelevant. This is not an issue with setting up JavaFX...

Comment: Ok, thanks for pointing.

Comment: Note an `InvocationTargetException` is not specific to FXML or even JavaFX. That exception is thrown when a constructor or method is invoked via reflection and said constructor or method throws an exception—the `InvocationTargetException` wraps the cause. Due to this, you _must_ look at the `Caused by:`s of such an exception to get the fundamental error (in your case, an `IllegalArgumentException`).

Answer (score 2):

The StackTrace points to the actual issue:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Children: duplicate children added: parent = Grid hgap=0.0, vgap=0.0, alignment=TOP_LEFT
```

Each `Node` may only be added to a `Scene` graph once. In your case, you call `center.add(txPhoneNumber...)` twice.

When trying to add it the second time, the compiler will fail and give the `IllegalArgumentException` you're seeing.

Remove the second attempt to add `txPhoneNumber` and this error will go away.